# Domain from A and hosting from B

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns

I have buyed domain from one company and hosting from another.
On hosting company website finded DNS addresses and applied them to domain hosting website(changed DNS) I done it yesterday, so today it should work, but: **Unable to resolve the server's DNS address** appears.

In direct admin control panel (DNS control) i have (it's my hosting company settings):
http://pastebin.com/MGbQ02hr

Note: IP and domain hidden!

Any ideas whats wrong ?

Comment: `nslookup ns1.provaider.com` + `ns2.provaider.com` will answer. BTW, MX RR for domain is just delirium (unrelated to topic, but detected)

Answer (score 1):

Simply do a whois search on your account provided to you by your Hosting provider, check to the see the NS they're using, if the name/ip matches the ones given to you when your account was activated and point that NS to your domain name and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

"*.provaider.com" addresses can't be resolved, as it written in clean English.

**Don't mask** domain, nobody will be able to debug *your troubles* without real data!

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem with your DNS server. Maybe you can try to ask your provider to configure ns2/alternate ns for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the DNS of web host to the DNS of domain registrar and not vice versa.